# Share data between web services

Tags: web-services, iis

I want to create two web services, A and B, hosted in IIS. A is used to updated a variable X and B to retrieve the value of X.

The question is whether I can make this work by declaring X as a static class variable. If not, what can I do ?

PS: Combining them into a single service is not an option for me.

Comment: Are the web services part of one website? Different websites? Same machine? Different machines?

Comment: WCF or ASMX? Can you give a bit more information, including why it's not acceptable to make them "one service", and what you mean by that? Maybe make two services that share the same static class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply YES. One can use static variable since all instances of the web service are executed in the same app domain.